# why is awaitReactions not a function? | discord.js v13

Tags: discord.js

I found some code which allows me to create a rock paper scissors game. However, it did need some updating and so I'm attempting to update it. I keep getting this error where `.awaitReactions is not a function`.

Code:

```
   const rpsEmbed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Let\'s play rock, paper, scissors!")
    .setColor('#a7a5f3')
    .setDescription("Select your choice by reacting: \n - Rock \n - Paper\n✂️ - Scissors")
    .setFooter("You have 15 seconds to answer!")

    var rps = ["", "", "✂️"]
    const m = message.channel.send({ embeds: [rpsEmbed] })
    .then(async rpsR => {
        await rpsR.react("");
        await rpsR.react("");
        await rpsR.react("✂️");

        const reacted = await promptMessage(m, message.author, 15, rps);
        const botChoice = rps[Math.floor(Math.random()*rps.length)];
        const result = await getResult(reacted, botChoice);

        rpsEmbed
        .setDescription("")
        .addField(result, `${reacted} vs ${botChoice}`)

    });

    async function getResult(choice, botChosen) {
        message.reactions.removeAll();
      if(choice === "" && botChoice === "✂️") {
          return message.channel.send("You win! I had fun, let's play again!");
        } else if (choice === "" && botChoice === "") {
          return message.channel.send("You win! I had fun, let's play again!");
        } else if (choice === "✂️" && botChoice === ""){
          return message.channel.send("You win! I had fun, let's play again!");
        } else if (choice === botChosen) {
          return message.channel.send("It's a tie!");
        } else {
          return message.channel.send("You lost! I had fun, let's play again!");
        }
    }

    async function promptMessage(rpsM, author, time, validReactions) {
        time *= 1000;
        const filter = (reaction, user) => validReactions.includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === author.id;
        return rpsM
            .awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: time})
            .then(collected => collected.first() && collected.first().emoji.name);
    }
```

It just gets up to sending the embed for the user to react with one of the emojis then crashes as soon as it has made its final reaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to await the promise [`TextChannel#send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send)

```js
const rpsR = await message.channel.send({ embeds: [rpsEmbed] })
await rpsR.react("");
await rpsR.react("");
await rpsR.react("✂️");

const reacted = await promptMessage(rpsR, message.author, 15, rps);
const botChoice = rps[Math.floor(Math.random()*rps.length)];
        const result = await getResult(reacted, botChoice);

rpsEmbed
  .setDescription("")
  .addField(result, `${reacted} vs ${botChoice}`)
```

I also changed it where you don't use a `.then()`